# Change the 2nd and 3rd pickerView acording to what row from the 1st picker is selected

Tags: swift, uipickerview, uipickerviewdatasource

I have 3 pickers like this: the 1st one is the generalPicker, the 2nd and 3rd are the same. In the generalPicker, I have an array (menu): ["Length", "Volume",  "Mass"] and every time I want to choose, for example Mass from the generalPicker, I want to get in the 2nd and 3rd pickers this array: ["Milligram", "Centigram", "Gram", "Kilogram", "Stone", "Pound", "Ounce"].

Or, if I chose in the generalPicker, let's say, Length, then I want to get in the 2nd and 3rd pickers: ["Millimeter", "Centimeter", "Meter", "Kilometer", "Foot", "Yard", "Mile"].

Can anyone give me an idea of how can I actually do that? A sample of my code (the pickers config):

```
func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int  {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {

    if pickerView.tag == 0 || pickerView.tag == 1 {
        return self.pickerLength.count
    } else if pickerView.tag == 2 {
        return self.pickerGeneral1.count
    }

    return 3
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {

    if pickerView.tag == 0 || pickerView.tag == 1{
        return self.pickerLength[row]
    } else if pickerView.tag == 2 {
        return self.pickerGeneral1[row]
    }

    return ""
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)  {

    if pickerView.tag == 0  {
        self.pickerTextField.text = self.pickerLength[row]
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }else if pickerView.tag == 1 {
        self.pickedTextField2.text = self.pickerLength[row]
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }else if pickerView.tag == 2 {
        self.pickerGeneral.text = self.pickerGeneral1[row]
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }
}
```

Arrays defs :

```
private var pickerMass = ["Milligram", "Centigram", "Gram", "Kilogram", "Stone", "Pound", "Ounce"]
private var pickerVolume = ["Milliliter", "Centiliter", "Liter", "Gallon", "Quart", "Pint", "Fluid ounce"]
private var pickerLength = ["Millimeter", "Centimeter", "Meter", "Kilometer", "Foot", "Yard", "Mile"]
private var pickerGeneral1 = ["Length", "Volume",  "Mass"]
```

Comment: Can you show code for array definition / population?

Comment: Sure! I update it!

Comment: You need to have some relational connection between your arrays so that you can filter the 2nd & 3rd arrays based on the value of the 1st one. E.g. right now if you choose "Mass" in pickerGeneral how do you know which values to show in the other 2 arrays?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following is the working code. It is certainly not the pretty way to do the work but will give an idea to resolve the issue.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var textField_0: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var textField_1: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var textField_2: UITextField!

private var pickerGeneral1 = ["Length", "Volume", "Mass"]

// Maintaining the other arrays as single array of arrays for efficient loading 
private var subContentArray = [["Millimeter", "Centimeter", "Meter", "Kilometer", "Foot", "Yard", "Mile"],
    ["Milliliter", "Centiliter", "Liter", "Gallon", "Quart", "Pint", "Fluid ounce"],
    ["Milligram", "Centigram", "Gram", "Kilogram", "Stone", "Pound", "Ounce"]]

var picker_0 = UIPickerView()
var picker_1 = UIPickerView()
var picker_2 = UIPickerView()

// To keep track of user's current selection from the main content array
private var _currentSelection: Int = 0

// whenever current selection is modified, we need to reload other pickers as their content depends upon the current selection index only.
var currentSelection: Int {
    get {
        return _currentSelection
    }
    set {
        _currentSelection = newValue
        picker_1 .reloadAllComponents()
        picker_2 .reloadAllComponents()

        textField_0.text = pickerGeneral1[_currentSelection]
        textField_1.text = subContentArray[_currentSelection][0]
        textField_2.text = subContentArray[_currentSelection][0]
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    currentSelection = 0;

    picker_0.delegate = self
    picker_0.dataSource = self
    picker_0.tag = 0

    picker_1.delegate = self
    picker_1.dataSource = self
    picker_1.tag = 1

    picker_2.delegate = self
    picker_2.dataSource = self
    picker_2.tag = 2

    textField_0.inputView = picker_0
    textField_1.inputView = picker_1
    textField_2.inputView = picker_2
}

func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    if pickerView.tag == 0 {
        return pickerGeneral1.count
    } else {
        return subContentArray[currentSelection].count
    }
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    if pickerView.tag == 0 {
        return pickerGeneral1[row]
    } else {
        return subContentArray[currentSelection][row]
    }
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    if pickerView.tag == 0 {
        currentSelection = row

        textField_0.text = pickerGeneral1[row]
        textField_0.resignFirstResponder()
    } else if pickerView.tag == 1 {
        textField_1.text = subContentArray[currentSelection][row]
        textField_1.resignFirstResponder()
    } else if pickerView.tag == 2 {
        textField_2.text = subContentArray[currentSelection][row]
        textField_2.resignFirstResponder()
    }
}
}
```

I would be using only one UIPickerView instead of 3.

Comment: Thanks alot! Can you please explain me the get/set ? What exactly is that doing ?

Comment: i am maintaining a variable to keep track of user's selection from "pickerGeneral1" array because the content of the other two pickers depend upon that. Bring that said, 'get' is called whenever we try to access the current selection index whereas 'set' is called when we try to set a new value for the 'currentSelection' variable. Hence, whenever the current selection changes, the content of the pickers need to be updated so am reloading them.

Comment: Also, we are filling up the content of the last two pickers on the basis of current selection index only. "return subContentArray[currentSelection][row]"

Comment: Thanks for the explains'!

Comment: One more q : What if wanna do, let's say, a default "Mass" form general and millimeter in centimeter (or whatever from the mass array) as a default set in pickers (when I open my app) ?! ...if I don't want the pickers to be empty when I open my app?! Any idea...?!

Comment: Thanks alot for all the effort and explains! You really get me to understand how pickers work! Thanks!!!!

Comment: you'r welcome @DaniTurc. Now that you understand the picker view. I would suggest try to use 1 picker view instead of 3.

Answer (score -1):

I think you could try using a dictionary instead of arrays. A dictionary of type [ String : String array ] would mean that your dictionary key would hold the category (e.g. Mass) and the value would hold an array of category items (e.g. milligram, centigram - both linked to Mass).

```
var dictionary: [String:[String]] = 
    [
        "length" : ["Millimeter", "Centimeter", "Meter", "Kilometer", "Foot", "Yard", "Mile"],
        "mass" : ["Milligram", "Centigram", "Gram", "Kilogram", "Stone", "Pound", "Ounce"]
    ]

if let item = dictionary["length"] {
     print(item)
} else {
     print("not found")
}
```